# labeling row and col names when using dist() and as.matrix()

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, distance

I was wondering if there is a specific parameter to output a table with all the row names when using dist() and as.matrix(). Here's what I mean:

```
first=c('john', 'judy', 'jenny')
second=c(3,6,9)
third = c(2,4,6)
df = data.frame(first,second,third)
```

I have this data frame called df:

```
 first second third
1  john      3     2
2  judy      6     4
3 jenny      9     6
```

Here's my desired output:

```
      john       judy   jenny
john 0.000000 4.41588 8.831761
judy 4.415880 0.00000 4.415880
jenny 8.831761 4.41588 0.000000
```

This is my code:

```
df.dist=dist(df)
df.dist=as.matrix(df.dist, labels=TRUE)
df.dist
```

And Here's what R is giving me:

```
      1       2        3
1 0.000000 4.41588 8.831761
2 4.415880 0.00000 4.415880
3 8.831761 4.41588 0.000000
```

I was wondering if there is a specific function or parameter that renames the columns when comparing different entries, or do we just need to code that ourselves?

Another thing that I saw when I typed ?as.matrix is that there is a param called dimnames that lets you input list of names for cols and rows. But I don't know if this would be such a good idea since my dataset has about 100+ entries.

Any help is deeply appreciated. Been stuck for a while.

Comment: Can you include a `dput()` of your `df` data.frame as described in [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's unclear if you have a column with names or if the names are row-names of the data.frame. If you have mixed character and numeric values `dist()` should be throwing an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is only one line of code to add these names as row and column names:

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text='first second third
1 john      3     2
2 judy      6     4
3 jenny      9     6')

df.dist=dist(df)
df.dist=as.matrix(df.dist, labels=TRUE)
colnames(df.dist) <- rownames(df.dist) <- df[['first']] #this is the only line

> df.dist
          john    judy    jenny
john  0.000000 4.41588 8.831761
judy  4.415880 0.00000 4.415880
jenny 8.831761 4.41588 0.000000
```

dimnames adds the names as attributes so you might be better off with the above.

Comment: Or, starting from `df.dist = dist(df)`, you could also do: `"dimnames<-"(as.matrix(df.dist), list(df[["first"]], df[["first"]]))`. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the first column as the data frame `rownames`, then use `dist`:

```
rownames(df) <- df$first
as.matrix(dist(df[-1]))

#          john     judy    jenny
#john  0.000000 3.605551 7.211103
#judy  3.605551 0.000000 3.605551
#jenny 7.211103 3.605551 0.000000
```